# Saving 30-Feb on Mysql (Date Formating)

Tags: mysql, types, crud

I have a problem saving 'contable dates' because every month on this way has 30 days each. I need to save a element (2014-02-30) using a type date-like (not a varchar/text/blob/etc) to save this because in this project we need that. Is it possible?

Comment: Save it as a date and format it when you select it.

Comment: i don't think so. you might need to store it as a number.

Comment: I agree with @JohnConde, to get the most out of the DBMS, save the dates and convert them for use in the application.

Comment: @JohnConde it is impossible to insert `2014-02-30` into a datetime field, in any DBMS I know of. The last day of February this year was the 28th.

Comment: Have a look at the sql_mode [ALLOW_INVALID_DATES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_allow_invalid_dates). It's possible to store then such a value in a `DATE` or `DATETIME` column and get this value back as stored.

Comment: @VMai thx, pls post this as answer.

Comment: When i say date-like i mean validating YYYY-MM-DD, the format and not the content. I know 2014-02-30 is not possible, but i need to save it and validate it (on every step of the software, including MYSQL)

Comment: @zyexal: It looks like a DATE and `SELECT DAY('2014-02-30')` will return 30 as expected, but other date and time functions, i.e. `SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, '2014-02-30', '2014-03-30')` will return 28. I don't know if this meets the requirements of OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Saving such a DATE "value" in a `DATE` or `DATETIME` column is possible using the sql_mode [ALLOW_INVALID_DATES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_allow_invalid_dates) and no strict mode:

> ALLOW_INVALID_DATES
>
> Do not perform full checking of dates. Check only that the month is in
>   the range from 1 to 12 and the day is in the range from 1 to 31. This
>   is very convenient for Web applications where you obtain year, month,
>   and day in three different fields and you want to store exactly what
>   the user inserted (without date validation). This mode applies to DATE
>   and DATETIME columns. It does not apply TIMESTAMP columns, which
>   always require a valid date.

So checking the date for an allowed contable date could be done with triggers, since there's no other check too. I assume that for this application the 31th of each month would be an invalid date.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE example (
  contable_date DATE NOT NULL
) ENGINE=INNODB;

-- set the sql_mode (here for the session)
SET @@SESSION.sql_mode = 'ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

INSERT INTO example (contable_date) VALUES ("2014-02-30");

SELECT 
    DAY(contable_date) as cday,
    MONTH(contable_date) as cmonth,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, contable_date, '2014-03-30') as cdiff
FROM 
    example;
```

Result:

```
cday  cmonth  cdiff
-------------------
  30       2     28
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/652fd/3)

Using MySQL Workbench I get with

```
SELECT contable_date FROM example
```

following result:

```
contable_date
-------------
   2014-02-30
```

but this doesn't work at sqlfiddle.com.

I wouldn't recommend this though, especially because one's not able to use strict SQL mode. One should consider the effect on the date and time functions too.

Comment: Can i use this to save the date and unset this option again in the same sql?, like SET ALLOW_INVALID_DATES = 1; 'Mysql query'; SET ALLOW_INVALID_DATES = 0;

Comment: You can do that and the SELECTs will still work, see [my updated fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/63e0f/1). Even an `ORDER BY` will have the 30th of February as earlier than the 1th of March.