# DATEFORMAT() in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I want to insert into table some particular values. However, I can not add date to my table. Other values can be added easily. I used this query

```
INSERT INTO `student` (`bdate`) VALUES ('30.05.1992');
```

I need to add in this format. I tried to use `DATE_FORMAT('30.05.1992','%d.%m.%y')`
it also didn't help.

Comment: You forgot the quotes around the second argument to `DATE_FORMAT`.

Comment: Do it the opposit way. Insert `bdate` with accepted format like `1992-05-30` and format the data while reading ;)

Comment: @zyexal You mean `accepted`. `excepted` is the opposite.

Comment: @Barmar Yes man Fixed quotes but it didn't help me.

Comment: The function should be `str_to_date`, not `date_format`.

Comment: `date_format` is for date->string, `str_to_date` is for string->date.

Comment: it doesn't work with both of date_format and str_to_date. When I tried to use str_to_date: I got error like below
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Truncated incorrect date value: '30.05.1997'

Comment: Please have a look [here - MySQL date format](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5367816/2675129)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO `student` (`bdate`) VALUES (STR_TO_DATE('30.05.1992', '%d.%m.%Y'));
```

Comment: what is the type of ``bdate`` ?

Comment: @Soulmaster Because you had a syntax error, see my comment above.

Comment: @mmuzahid , type of bdate is date

Comment: `%y` should be `%Y`, because it's a 4-digit year.

Comment: @Soulmaster : As far I know you cant change date field format a DB level. Just change it when you need to display it.

Comment: @All [VMais answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25877242/saving-30-feb-on-mysql-date-formating/25878260#25878260) might be interesting for you.

Comment: If you check data in table then it will be yyyy-mm-dd format then what is benefit to insert in this way.

Comment: @ZafarMalik :  may be Soulmaster getting the value at this format from some source and storing it as Date

Comment: @zyexal thanks for VMais answer, it was interesting :)

Comment: @Soulmaster if the answer helps you...you could accept it as answer

Answer (score 0):

If your field type is date then you can insert data in yyyy-mm-dd format only, even at the time of fetching data you can convert it into your own format.

If you want to insert date in your own format then you can use varchar data type, even at the time of fetching data it will not be optimized and you can get slowness.

Comment: Is there anyway to put date like 05.05.2005 keeping field type as date?

Comment: no. its not possible. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-literals.html

Comment: when you can easily convert date format at the time of fetching data then why are you bother to insert in specific format.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
INSERT INTO `student` (`bdate`) VALUES (STR_TO_DATE('30.05.1992', '%d.%m.%Y'));
```

as year is 4 digit such that 1992,so it should be %Y